# Group by an object in an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift2, grouping

I have two objects. One called `EstimateItem` and the other one is called `Part` (`Part` class is inherited from Realm's [`Object`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Object.html) class). One `EstimateItem` can have multiple `Part`s.

```
class EstimateItem {
    var parts: [Part]?
}
```

There's an array of `EstimateItem`s with different numbers of `Part`s in each instance.

```
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|         EstimateItem           |            Parts                |
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| Line Item 1 - RnR WDH - Twins  |  Epoxy / Wood for lami          |
| (single)                       |                                 |
|                                |                                 |
| Line Item 2 - RnR WDH - Twins  |  Epoxy / Wood for lami          |
| (double)                       |                                 |
|                                |                                 |
|Line Item 3 - Install sash lock |Epoxy / Wood for lami / Sash lock|
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

I need to group them by specific `Part`. It should look something like this.

[image]

How do I do this?

I couldn't figure out a way to do this while the parts are *attached* to individual item so I tried laying them all out in an array of `(part: Part, item: EstimateItem)` tuples.

```
var groups = [(part: Part, item: EstimateItem)]()
for item in estimateItemsArray {
    if let parts = item.parts {
        for part in parts {
            groups.append((part, item))
        }
    }
}

// Epoxy - RnR WDH - Twins (single)
// Wood for lami - RnR WDH - Twins (single)
// Epoxy - RnR WDH - Twins (double)
// Wood for lami - RnR WDH - Twins (double)
// Epoxy - RnR WDH - Twins (single)
// Wood for lami - RnR WDH - Twins (single)
// Sash lock, traditional - Install sash lock
```

And then group it.

But I'm still stuck. Also I feel like I'm overcomplicating it and I was wondering if there's an easier and more *Swifty* way of doing this.

Comment: Can I assume you have an array of all parts and items? Like a `var parts : [Part]`?

Comment: @luk2302 There's no separate array of parts. There's an array of items called `estimateItemsArray `. And in each item, there's an array of parts like you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I came up with trying to find a more *swifty* way of doing this is the following:

```
let parts = Set(estimateItemsArray.flatMap{ $0.parts ?? [] })

let partMap = parts.map { part in
    return (part, estimateItemsArray.filter {
            $0.parts?.indexOf(part) != nil
        }
    )
}
```

`partMap` now contains tuples of the form `(Part, [EstimateItem])`. The only requirement is for `Part` to conform to `Hashable` or something related - in my test I just let Part inherit from `NSObject`.

Explanation:

- create an array of all the available parts (`Set` to ensure uniqueness)
- loop over the array mapping and returning a tuple of

  - the actual part
  - loop over `estimateItemsArray` filtering out the items that have the current part in their list

*The complete test-data looks like this*

```
/* the now classes, both include some identifier to distinguish them */
class Item {
    var n : String
    var parts : [Part]? = [Part]()
    init(n:String) {
        self.n = n
    }
}

class Part : NSObject {
    var n : String
    init(n:String) {
        self.n = n
    }
}

/* set up the test data */
let item1 = Item(n: "item 1")
let item2 = Item(n: "item 2")
let item3 = Item(n: "item 3")

let part1 = Part(n: "part 1")
let part2 = Part(n: "part 2")
let part3 = Part(n: "part 3")

item1.parts = [part1, part2]
item2.parts = [part1, part3]
item3.parts = [part1, part2, part3]

var arrItems = [item1, item2, item3]

/* actual logic */
let parts = Set(arrItems.flatMap{ $0.parts ?? [] })

let partMap = parts.map { part in
    return (part, arrItems.filter {
            $0.parts?.indexOf(part) != nil
        }
    )
}

/* final output */
partMap.forEach { entry in
    print("part \(entry.0.n)")
    entry.1.forEach {
        print("contains \($0.n)")
    }
}
```

Outputting:

> part part 1
>   contains item 1
>   contains item 2
>   contains item 3
>   part part 3
>   contains item 2
>   contains item 3
>   part part 2
>   contains item 1
>   contains item 3

If you cannot inherit from `NSObject` like I initially though, make your class `Part` conform to `Hashable` which is the requirement for sets:

```
class Part : Hashable {
    var n : String
    init(n:String) {
        self.n = n
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        return n.hashValue // you basically have to provide some kind of logic based on *your* Part object
    }
}

func ==(lhs: Part, rhs: Part) -> Bool {
    return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately there's a snag. I'm using Realm and the `Part` class is inherited from Realm's own `Object` class and cannot be modified to inherit from `NSObject`. My bad for not mentioning it in my question. So I'm getting the error **Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Set<_>' with an argument list of type '([Part])'** on the first line. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: This is strange because Realm's [`Object`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Object.html) class is inherited from a class called `RLMObjectBase` which is inherited from `NSObject` itself. But still I'm getting that error though.

Comment: @Isuru I was christmas shopping, will take a look at it right now.

Comment: @Isuru I updated my answer - I do not know how Realm reacts to that, maybe there is already a `hashValue` implementation or an `==` one!